# Connecting a PostgreSQL database in ArcGIS Pro gives instance/server machine error

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-pro

I am trying to connect an PostgreSQL database made using pgAdmin 4 in ArcGIS Pro 2.0.1. PostgreSQL version is 10.0.

I tried several methods of connecting and how easy it is in QGIS I cannot find the reason why it doesn't work in ArcGIS Pro.

I followed the steps [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/connect-postgresql.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C53BF81BCB91414ABB1E2CF0C006E5C9), edited the pg_hba.conf file even by making so all connections to the database are allowed thinking this would be the issue but this didn't help.

I am configuring it like this now:

[image: Database connection in ArcGIS pro]

Where my database name in PGAdmin is this:

[image: PGAdmin database list]

I am using regular settings:

host name: localhost
port: 5432
username: postgres

But yet, whatever I try, this error pops up:

[image: Error message]

What I am doing wrong? This is my first time doing it on ArcGIS Pro and I didn't have any problems using other software.

Comment: Do not ***ever*** use the `postgres` user for trivial connection tests. Proper practice is to create a minimally privileged login (e.g. "test" or "proj1user"). You may be using an unsupported PostgreSQL release -- please [edit] the question to specify the exact PG version. Your problem is likely that your connection parameters are different -- `localhost` is not the same as `vrowl` (you must take proactive steps to permit connection on other than the loopback interface)

Comment: PostgreSQL 10 is not yet supported by any Esri release. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/databases/database-requirements-postgresql.htm

Comment: Well that explains it then. Thanks for the answer. Any indication when this will be supported?

Comment: 10.6 is due out soon; it will likely support 9.6, but I'm not convinced 10.0 will make the cut.

Comment: I am having the same problem, using the 9.6 version of PostgreSQL and 2.1.3 have gone through same channels/processes as user stated above

Comment: Strangely I can connect to my database (did have to rename my databases so they were lower case), but I simply can't add data to a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Vince answered this:

PostgreSQL 10 is not supported by any Esri releases.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/databases/database-requirements-postgresql.htm

Requirements for the current version (2.1):

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/manage-postgresql/database-requirements-postgresql.htm

Still no PostgreSQL 10 sadly.